# Как убрать порт из url nginx. Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

Поднял docker, приложение открывается по запросу http://test-app012:10007/10007/. Таких контейнеров в докере у меня несколько у меня несколько (пример http://test-app012:10008/10008 итд). Как убрать номер порта из url, чтобы при запросе был урл http://test-app012/10007/, но при этом редирект был на порт 10007?

Comment: вы хотите настроить nginx как load balancer? чтобы сайт был доступен на дефолтном (80) порту, а перенаправлялся трафик на 10007, 10008 и т.д.?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten
У меня уже так так настроено:
Один сервер - на нем куча контейнеров которые открываются  по портам 10007, 10008 итд
Я хочу преобразовать url каждого контейнера 
http://test-app012:10007/10007/ в http://test-app012/10007/
длаее
http://test-app012:10008/10008/ в http://test-app012/10008/
итд.